# Poll HTTP endpoint in Meteor

Tags: meteor, single-page-application

I am trying to get some info from an API and save this info into a mongodb collection and finally display this information reactively. When the page is loaded it does it perfectly. If I make a manual update in mongo the view changes instantly as well. But after the first load, the page doesn't make new requests anymore, so the external data is no longer refreshed.

I understand that meteor looks for internal data changes, but I didn't find anything to look for external changes, or to make the requests in a loop.

```
<template name="scanner">
  {{#each scan}}
    <img src="img/antenna.png" height="25" width="25" style={{position_scanner x y}}
      id="{{addr}}" title="{{tip_text addr name}}" >
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.scanner.helpers({
  scan: function() {
    Meteor.call("get_scanners");
    return Scanners.find({});
  }
});

Meteor.methods({
  get_scanners: function (){
    var url = "http://192.168.60.154:5008/api-ot/scanners";
    try {
      var result = HTTP.get(url);
      var statusCode = result.statusCode;
      var data = result.data.scanners_list;
      for (var x in data) {
        var scanner = data[x];
        Scanners.update({ addr: scanner.addr }, scanner, { upsert: true });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Cannot get scanner data");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? How often do you want to refresh that external API?

Comment: I have a API that returns data of some beacons. I want to get the position of this beacons and print then in a blueprints. I dont know, maybe refreshing every 10 seconds could be a nice try.

Comment: Does this refresh need to continue as long as the user is logged in or only while they are looking at a specific page? Does the same data get published to all users? (it looks like it from your code)

Comment: In fact, there is only one user and i wish that refresh would be unstoppable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want your external call to happen every 10 seconds, you can just do it in [Meteor.startup()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-startup) using [Meteor.setInterval()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html#Meteor-setInterval) to schedule it. You are updating the `Scanners` collection which can be sent to the client via publish & subscribe, no `Meteor.call()` necessary!

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  Meteor.setInterval(() => {
    const = "http://192.168.60.154:5008/api-ot/scanners";
    try {
      const data = HTTP.get(url).data.scanners_list;
      data.forEach(scanner => {
        Scanners.update({ addr: scanner.addr }, scanner, { upsert: true });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Cannot get scanner data");
    }
  },10000); // run every 10 seconds == 10000 msec
});
```

Comment: It worked, thank you Michel. I just made some adjusts, but this function set interval saved my life.